# Passing arguments to a function from a bound button

Tags: python, tkinter

I generated a grid of buttons with row and col.
I then bind the buttons with a left and right click and pass the row and col of the clicked button but could not make it work.

Here is what i did.

```
def initialize(self):
    self.grid()

    frame = gui.Frame(self)
    frame.pack()

    for col in range(x_length):
        for row in range(y_length):
            button = gui.Button(frame,text=str(col) + ":" + str(row))
            button.grid(column=col,row=row) 
            button.bind('<Button-1>',lambda col=col, row=row: self.on_left_click(self, row, col))
            button.bind('<Button-3>',lambda col=col, row=row: self.on_right_click(self, row, col))

def on_left_click(self, event, row, col):
    self.some_function(event, "left", row, col)

def on_right_click(self, event, row, col):
    self.some_function(event, "right", row, col)

def some_function(self, event, click, row, col):
    print('{} click on {}:{}'.format(click, row, col))
```

It is retrieving the row coordinate but not the col coordinate.

```
   right click on <tkinter.Event object at 0x0000000002FA44E0>:6
   left click on <tkinter.Event object at 0x0000000002FA44E0>:4
   right click on <tkinter.Event object at 0x0000000002FA44A8>:7
```

I am learning Python and any help is appreciated.
I already saw similar problems posted with answers but this might be different.